# Dynamically create test file templates for your entire repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've been looking around, but I haven't been able to find anything that does exactly what I want.

I was wondering if there's a utility out there that scans the structure and source code of your entire repo and creates a parallel test structure where one isn't there already, in which every single function and method in your code has an equivalent empty unit test.

It's pretty tedious to have to manually write a bunch of unit test boilerplate.

For example, assuming this project structure:

```
myproject
|--src
   |--__init__.py
   |--a.py
   |--subpackage
      |--__init__.py
      |--b.py
      |--c.py
```

It should create:

```
myproject
|--src
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--a.py
|  |--subpackage
|     |--__init__.py
|     |--b.py
|     |--c.py
|
|--tests
   |--test_a.py
   |--subpackage
      |--test_b.py
      |--test_c.py
```

And if the contents of a.py are:

```
class Printer:
    def print_normal(self, text):
        print(text)

    def print_upper(self, text):
        print(str(text).upper())

    def print_lower(self, text):
        print(str(text).lower())

def greet():
    print("Hi!")
```

It the contents of test_a.py should be something similar to this:

```
import pytest
from myproject.src import a

def test_Printer_print_normal():
    assert True

def test_Printer_print_upper():
    assert True

def test_Printer_print_lower():
    assert True

def test_greet():
    assert True
```

Is anyone aware of any python project that does something like this? Even if it isn't exactly the same, anything that would save some work when initially setting up the pytest boilerplate for a giant repo with hundreds of classes and thousands of methods would be a massive time-saver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO a very good question; looked for a similar tool myself for some time ago, something like what's offered by Netbeans/Pycharm IDEs to generate JUnit test classes from existing Java classes. Will write an answer with my findings soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for the tests generator tools in Python myself, I could find only those that generate `unittest`-style classes:

#### `pythoscope`

Installation of the latest version from Github:

```
$ pip2 install git+https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/pythoscope
```

Looks promising in theory: generates classes based on static code analysis in modules, maps the project structure to `tests` dir (one test module per library module), each function gets its own test class. The problem with this project is that it's pretty much abandoned: no Python 3 support, fails when encounters features backported to Python 2, thus IMO unusable nowadays. There are [pull requests](https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/pythoscope/pull/14) out there that claim to add Python 3 support, but they didn't work for me back then.

Nevertheless, here's what it would generate if your module would have Python 2 syntax:

```
$ pythoscope --init .
$ pythoscope spam.py
$ cat tests/test_spam.py
import unittest


class TestPrinter(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_print_lower(self):
        # printer = Printer()
        # self.assertEqual(expected, printer.print_lower())
        assert False  # TODO: implement your test here

    def test_print_normal(self):
        # printer = Printer()
        # self.assertEqual(expected, printer.print_normal())
        assert False  # TODO: implement your test here

    def test_print_upper(self):
        # printer = Printer()
        # self.assertEqual(expected, printer.print_upper())
        assert False  # TODO: implement your test here

class TestGreet(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_greet(self):
        # self.assertEqual(expected, greet())
        assert False  # TODO: implement your test here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

#### Auger

Installation from PyPI:

```
$ pip install auger-python
```

Generates tests from runtime behavior. While it may be an option for tools with a command line interface, it requires writing an entrypoint for libraries. Even with tools, it will only generate tests for stuff that was explicitly requested; if a function is not executed, no test will be generated for it. This makes it only partially useable for tools (worst case is that you have to run the tool multiple times with all options activated to cover the completed code base) and hardly useable with libraries.

Nevertheless, this is what Auger would generate from an example entrypoint for your module:

```
# runner.py

import auger
import spam

with auger.magic([spam.Printer], verbose=True):
    p = spam.Printer()
    p.print_upper()
```

Executing the `runner.py` yields:

```
$ python runner.py
Auger: generated test: tests/test_spam.py
$ cat tests/test_spam.py
import spam
from spam import Printer
import unittest


class SpamTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_print_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            Printer.print_upper(self=<spam.Printer object at 0x7f0f1b19f208>,text='fizz'),
            None
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

#### Custom tool

For a one-time job, it shouldn't be hard to write own AST visitor that generates the test stubs from existing modules. The example script `testgen.py` below generates simple test stubs using the same idea as `pythoscope`. Usage example:

```
$ python -m testgen spam.py 
class TestPrinter:
    def test_print_normal(self):
        assert False, "not implemented"


    def test_print_upper(self):
        assert False, "not implemented"


    def test_print_lower(self):
        assert False, "not implemented"


def test_greet():
    assert False, "not implemented"
```

Contents of `testgen.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import ast
import pathlib


class TestModuleGenerator(ast.NodeVisitor):

    linesep = '\n'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.imports = set()
        self.lines = []
        self.indent = 0
        self.current_cls = None

    @property
    def code(self):
        lines = list(self.imports) + [self.linesep] + self.lines
        return self.linesep.join(lines).strip()

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: ast.FunctionDef):
        arg_self = 'self' if self.current_cls is not None else ''
        self.lines.extend([
            '    ' * self.indent + f'def test_{node.name}({arg_self}):',
            '    ' * (self.indent + 1) + 'assert False, "not implemented"',
            self.linesep,
        ])
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node: ast.ClassDef):
        clsdef_line = '    ' * self.indent + f'class Test{node.name}:'
        self.lines.append(clsdef_line)
        self.indent += 1
        self.current_cls = node.name
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.current_cls = None
        if self.lines[-1] == clsdef_line:
            self.lines.extend([
                '  ' * self.indent + 'pass',
                self.linesep
            ])
        self.indent -= 1

    def visit_AsyncFunctionDef(self, node: ast.AsyncFunctionDef):
        self.imports.add('import pytest')
        self.lines.extend([
            '    ' * self.indent + '@pytest.mark.asyncio',
            '    ' * self.indent + f'async def test_{node.name}():',
            '    ' * (self.indent + 1) + 'assert False, "not implemented"',
            self.linesep,
        ])
        self.generic_visit(node)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'module',
        nargs='+',
        default=(),
        help='python modules to generate tests for',
        type=lambda s: pathlib.Path(s).absolute(),
    )
    modules = parser.parse_args().module
    for module in modules:
        gen = TestModuleGenerator()
        gen.visit(ast.parse(module.read_text()))
        print(gen.code)
```

Comment: can you please share official documentation and licensing for testgen.py? I want to use it in office codebase. I want to know if it is ok to use there.

Comment: @VivekAgrawal the script is just a one-time thing I used in a legacy project, so there are no docs besides the answer itself. regarding the license, feel free to use the code as you wish :-) but IIRC the Creative Commons license applies to all answers anyway, so there's no need to ask for permission.

Comment: I've created an open source github project using the custom tool created by you. See: https://github.com/vmnit/testgen
I've mentioned the source of the code in the README.md. Let me know if you want me to add anything there.